# Автозапуск shell скрипта на Android. Как осуществить?

Tags: android, bash, shell

Мне нужно запустить пару команд перед стартом оболочки:

```
echo 0x21 > /sys/kernel/debug/omap_mux/spi0_sclk
chmod 666 /dev/ttyO2
```

Но как это сделать? Я уже всё перепробовал, что нашёл. Создал shell-скрипт, проверил его работу запуском.

1. Переименовал в `01myscripts` ([отсюда](https://syslinux.ru/node/1311)), и с правами 755 положил
   в `/system/etc/init.d/`
2. Именовал обычно `script.sh`, и с правами 700 клал в `/su/su.d/` и в `/system/su.d/`
3. Заголовок делал и такой: `#!/system/bin/su` и такой: `#!/su/bin/sush`, как [здесь](https://su.chainfire.eu/)

Стоит SuperSU и Busybox. Скрипты работают, если их запустить командой `sh script.sh` или `sh 01myscripts`, то результат есть, но после запуска ничего не меняется.

Comment: в смысле ничего не меняется? не меняются права файла? или они не хотят запускаться сами?

Comment: Не меняется то, что я пытаюсь поменять в скрипте, а это права на UART и режим ножек процессора. При явном запуске они меняются, а после загрузки нет, значит скрипт при загрузке не выполняется.